# Solr with no text search

Tags: solr, solr6

I have successfully implemented the custom search in solr by extending CustomScoreProvider. But the problem is i need to pass some user info like 31,1 which i need in custom sort.

```
q={!mycustomparser}31+1+*:*
```

and it is acting as a text search. Is there any way that i can skip this text search and can just pass the user info.

some code.

```
public class MyCustomParserPlugin extends QParserPlugin {

    @Override
    public QParser createParser(String querystring, SolrParams slocParams, SolrParams params, SolrQueryRequest req) {
        return new MyCustomParser(querystring, slocParams, params, req);        
    }

    private static class MyCustomParser extends QParser{

        private Query inQuery;

        public MyCustomParser(String querystring, SolrParams slocParams, SolrParams params, SolrQueryRequest req) {
            super(querystring, slocParams, params, req);
            try {
                QParser parser = getParser(querystring, getReq());
                this.inQuery = parser.parse();
            }catch(SyntaxError ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("error parsing query", ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Query parse() throws SyntaxError {
            return new MatchingQuery(inQuery);
        }

    }

}
```

**=========================================**

```
public class MatchingQuery extends CustomScoreQuery {

    private Query subQuery;

    public MatchingQuery(Query subQuery) {
        super(subQuery);
        this.subQuery = subQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected CustomScoreProvider getCustomScoreProvider(LeafReaderContext context) {
        return new MyCustomSortClz(subQuery, context);
    }
}
```

**=========================================**

```
public class MyCustomSortClz extends CustomScoreProvider {

  // ---> my sort
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Local Parameters to achieve that - pass the user data in a local parameter and set the query to be just `*:*`.

From Solr documentation: "Local parameters provide a way to add meta-data to certain argument types such as query strings."

In your custom parser constructor you can access those parameters from the `SolrParams slocParams` variable.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/local-parameters-in-queries.html